# Best way to sum diff dates on child rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

i'm new on PowerBI.

My question is the next: i have a table with parent rows and childs rows. each row have a start datetime and end datetime

```
ItemId    | ParentId  | startDateTime         | endDateTime
1         | null      | 2017-12-12 xx:xx:xx   | 2017-12-12 xx:xx:xx
2         | 1         | 2017-12-12 xx:xx:xx   | 2017-12-12 xx:xx:xx
3         | 1         | 2017-12-14 xx:xx:xx   | 2017-12-15 xx:xx:xx
4         | null      | 2017-12-20 xx:xx:xx   | 2017-12-20 xx:xx:xx
5         | 4         | 2017-12-21 xx:xx:xx   | 2017-12-21 xx:xx:xx
6         | 4         | 2017-12-22 xx:xx:xx   | 2017-12-22 xx:xx:xx
```

...

i want to create a new column to save the startDateTime of the parent row and the endDateTime of the last child row and get the diff in hours between dates. For example for the item1 i need 48 hours  if it possible in M languaje?

thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: Sorry, My question is: wich is the best way to do this? M languaje, DAX or process data in other languaje and import table again in MYSQL with the new column processed

Comment: My question still is the same ;) What have you tried?

Comment: CALCULATE(COUNT(incidencias[id_padre] );FILTER(incidencias;incidencias[id_padre] <> BLANK() ) ) i have tried this but only get the total of childs,

Comment: Finally i tried DAX. reading other post i have created another table with the childs rows related to father row on the principal table. i have the following code but returns me an error  `tiempoResolucion = DATEDIFF(incidencias[fecha_inicio].[Date];incidencias[fecha_fin].[Date]; MINUTE) + CALCULATE( 
    SUMX(
        incidenciasHijas;
        DATEDIFF(incidenciasHijas[fecha_inicio].[Date];incidenciasHijas[fecha_fin].[Date]; MINUTE)
    ),
    incidencias[id_padre] <> BLANK()
)` **argunment 2 in calculate function is required**  but i have the argument 2 defined

Comment: How can item 1 return 48 hours?

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this in the Query Editor - first add a Merge step, joining to the "Current" query, using ItemId = ParentId.  Then I would Expand the resulting Table-type column, using the Aggregate option and choosing the endDateTime column.  The Editor will generate a Count function (the only option via the UI), but you can tweak the formula to List.Max in place of List.Count.

Then you can add a Custom Column to calculate what you need, something like:

= Duration.Days ( [Max of endDateTime] - [startDateTime] )